# How to unlock a USB Broadband Modem

Tags: modem, mobile-broadband, unlock

I have a *Huawei E303 modem* given by a *Mobile Broadband Service Provider*. I did *Pay* for it.

I had terminated the service from that service provider. But I cannot use that modem which I did pay to gain because it has been *Locked !*

Is there an Application in Ubuntu for getting *Unlock it ?*

Is this having a *legal issue ?* (If so I will remove this question)

I followed certain guides on certain sites but could not fix this.

Here is the *lsusb* output. *Last one* is the particular modem :

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10f1:1a34 Importek 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [Linux Huawei Unlocker](http://freecode.com/projects/linux-huawei-unlocker)

> Linux Huawei Unlocker is a tool that attempts to automatically remove the carrier lock on Huawei mobile broadband modems from the Linux command line. It automatically finds IMEIs, calculates unlock codes, checks SIM lock status, displays remaining unlock attempts, and asks the user for confirmation before trying the unlock code.

Comment: But it says `Could not identify active port`..

Comment: did you refer the readme file? http://paste.ubuntu.com/6447978/

Comment: sorry I was waiting for updating.. i installed Modem-manager-gui. Its a nice application. thanks. Yes. i dd all the steps. not needed to install python serial. (was already installed). It cannot identyfy that dongle. But it can detect my other dongle. Seems it is having problem with this model. 775159651

Comment: thanks.I couldn't try Huawei unlocker on my dongle cuz it is already unlocked. :(

Answer (score 1):

First install the Mobile partner Linux software. You can download the installation file from [here](http://nacitasyifa.web.id/content/download-mobile-partner-linux-20003-can-sms-and-voice-call-too).

Go to the file folder through terminal. Then enter:

```
sudo chmod +X install

./install
```

Connect the dongle with a "Foreign" SIM.

Then there will be a message to enter the Unlock Code.

Then visit the [huaweicodecalculator.com](http://huaweicodecalculator.com/new-algo/) and get the unlock code with entering the IMEI number of your Dongle.

** For Huawei E303 you need to get the Unlock Code with New Algorithum.

Then copy the Unlock Code and Paste it on the Mobile Partner message box and Press Unlock.

This will unock the Dongle.

Answer (score 1):

here is the site, which describes how to unlock usb modem in linux:

https://girobiro.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/unlock-3g-usb-dongles-in-linux/